Computing intersection of multiple cones with Python
I am trying to perform the intersection of 3 cones with python.
In particular, I'm using PyVista to generate the cones in the 3D space and then I use the boolean_intersection function to get the intersection of the three of them together. I encountered many different problems that I'll try to resume here. Since I'm new to Pyvista, maybe some of them will have an obvious answer!
the code that I wrote is this one:
# defining the cones 
dist = 150
apex1 = (0, 0, dist/2)
apex2 = (0, dist/2, 0)
apex3 = (dist/2, 0, 0)

direction1 = (0,0,1)
direction2 = (0,1,0)
direction3 = (1,0,0)

cone1 = pv.Cone(center=apex1, direction=direction1, height=dist, angle=10, resolution=12)
cone2 = pv.Cone(center=apex2, direction=direction2, height=dist, angle=10, resolution=12)
cone3 = pv.Cone(center=apex3, direction=direction3, height=dist, angle=10, resolution=12)

surf1 = cone1.extract_surface().triangulate()
surf2 = cone2.extract_surface().triangulate()
surf3 = cone3.extract_surface().triangulate()

intersection12 = surf1.boolean_intersection(surf2)
intersection_all = intersection12.boolean_intersection(surf3)

First of all, I noticed that the boolean_intersection works well when two cones are taken separately, but when I compute the intersection with the third one, the code fails without giving any error message. However, there are some particular cases in which it can evaluate the intersection of the three of them, this happens when I change the value of the distance (dist).
I also noticed that changing the resolution has an impact on the outcome of the script, for example, when I put resolution = 36 I got this error message:
2024-08-30 10:33:57.563 (   0.153s) [F50302D866F379EE]      vtkDelaunay2D.cxx:1435  WARN| vtkDelaunay2D (0000025E42E6F680): Edge not recovered, polygon fill not possible

other error messages encountered are of this kind:
2024-08-30 10:33:57.565 (   0.155s) [F50302D866F379EE]       vtkExecutive.cxx:730    ERR| vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0000025E42D48B40): Algorithm vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter (0000025E42EF92D0) returned failure for request: vtkInformation (0000025E42E67E30)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 3234
  Reference Count: 1
  Registered Events: (none)
  Request: REQUEST_DATA
  FORWARD_DIRECTION: 0
  ALGORITHM_AFTER_FORWARD: 1
  FROM_OUTPUT_PORT: 0

I am quiet sure that the geometry that I've chosen leads to an intersection (as I can see by plotting the cones), so I really don't understand why it doesn't work in some cases.
I would appreciate if someone could explain me how this algorithm works and what could be the problem in my code.
I thank you for any answer.

Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I can't seem to reproduce your issue: the code runs as expected when using pyvista 0.44.1 on python 3.12.5. What version of pyvista are you using?

yes, the version that I've uploaded is working correctly, I update the post with another example in which I had troubles. My python and pyvista versions are the same as you
